# Got error while using scrapy

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, scrapy

I'm trying to extract data using scrapy, I followed [the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1EFnX1UkXVU) but i'm getting error

`test.py`

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from craigslist_sample.items import CraigslistSampleItem
from scrapy.http import Request

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "craig"
    allowed_domain = ["craigslist.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/sfc/npo"]

    def parse(self,response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        titles = hxs.select("//p")
        items = []
        for titles in titles:
            item = CraigslistSampleItem()
            item["title"] = titles.select("a/text()").extract()
            item["link"] = titles.select("a/@href").extract()
            item.append(item)
        return items
```

`items.py`

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class CraigslistSampleItem(Item):
    title = Field()
    link = Field()#import scrapy
```

these are two files

after running the `test.py` I got following error

```
test.py:1: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Module `scrapy.spider` is deprecated, use `scrapy.spiders` instead
  from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    from craigslist_sample.items import CraigslistSampleItem
ImportError: No module named craigslist_sample.items
```

So what changes must be done by me please suggest as early as possible....

And version of my scrapy is 1.1.2 & python version is 2.7.6

Thank You....:)